# NoSuchElementException при считывании файла с помощью Scanner

Tags: java, файлы

Пытаюсь считать содержимое файла. Для этой цели сначала был написан такой код:

```
public static String readFile() throws IOException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    String s = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}
```

Код отлично работает, однако не считывает больше одной строки (что, в целом, предсказуемо). Попробовала написать цикл для выведения текста:

```
public static String readFile() throws IOException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    String s = input.nextLine();
    String content = null;
    while (input.nextLine() != null)
    {
        content += s;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}
```

Выдает ошибку, но я никак не могу понять, в чем она заключается:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>           at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1554)
>           at aspu.haffman.timofeeva.utils.Runner.readFile(Runner.java:36) //Строка, где начинается цикл while
>           at aspu.haffman.timofeeva.utils.Runner.main(Runner.java:17) //Строка, где в методе main я вызываю функцию

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String s = readFile();
}
```

Comment: Без текста ошибки мы тоже вряд ли сможем понять в чем она заключается....

Comment: приложите трейс ошибки к вопросу, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/805229/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте читать так, это более правильно:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                    stringBuilder.append(input.nextLine());
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
                System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает наконец-то!))))

Answer (score 4):

1. Со `Scanner`-ом не работает "пока считанное значение не равно `null`": попытка считать отсутствующую строку приводит к `throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found")`. Проверять наличие строк нужно с помощью метода [hasNextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())
2. Возвращать нужно `content`, а не `s`
3. Начальным значением `content` должно быть `""`
4. Не помешает закрывать открытый файл

В итоге:

```
public static String readFile() throws IOException
{
    String content = "";
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")))
    {
        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            content += input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(content);
    return content;
}
```